# Difference between UnPin and Close UnPinned

Tags: delphi, dock

When the user clicks 'x' on a Pinned Form OnClose is called.

When the user clicks 'x' on an Unpinned Form OnHide is called

When the user clicks 'UnPin' on a Pinned Form OnHide is called.

I'm trying to synchronise the visible forms with a menu system but I don't know how to determine the difference in the OnHide event between when the user clicks 'x' and when the user clicks 'UnPin'.  I want to intercept the 'x' and call Close instead.

[image: Menu with ticks]

Each child is a descendant of TManagerPanel which in turn is a descendant of TForm with the border style set to bsSizeToolWin, Drag Kind set to dkDock and Drag Mode is dmAutomatic.

```
type
    TPanelManager = class(TForm)
    ...
    private
    ...        
        Panels: TManagerPanelList;
        Settings: TSettings; //User Settings
    ...
end;
...

function TPanelManager.InitChild(ChildClass: TManagerPanelClass): TManagerPanel;
var
    Child: TManagerPanel;
begin
    Child := ChildClass.Create(Self);
    Child.Connection := MSConnection1;
    Child.Settings := Settings;
    Child.Styles := Styles;
    ...
    Child.OnPanelClosed := PanelClosed;
    Child.OnPercentChanged := PercentChanged;
    ...
    Child.OnPanelHide := PanelHide;
    Child.Font := Font;
    Child.Initialise;
    Child.ManualDock(DockTarget);
    Panels.AddPanel(Child);
    Result := Child;
end;

procedure TPanelManager.PanelClosed(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
var
    MenuItem: TMenuItem;
    Child: TManagerPanel;
begin
    if Sender is TManagerPanel then
    begin
        Child := TManagerPanel(Sender);
        Action := caFree;
        MenuItem := MenuItemFromChild(Child);
        MenuItem.Checked := False;
        Settings[RemoveAmpersand(MenuItem.Caption)] := MenuItem.Checked;
        Panels.Remove(Child);
    end;
end;
```

EDIT:
What I mean by a "Pinned" Form: A docked form with the pin set such that it always visible.
[image: Pinned]

What I mean by a "UnPinned" Form: A docked form with the pin released such that a tab appears in a dock tab set and the form appears when the tab is selected.

[image: Unpinned - Expanded]

[image: Unpinned]

Delphi Version is 2007

Comment: What is a _pinned form_?

Comment: @jachguate... thought someone might ask that, I mean a dockable form like the structure view in the Delphi IDE where it is currently set so that it doesn't hide when it loses focus - I've updated the question to try and make this clear.

Comment: Hmm, looks like the Delphi experts on SO don't use docking forms.....

Comment: @David, I thought this would be simple....is my question confusing or is it really that no one knows the answer? I find that very hard to believe.

Comment: @JamesB What Delphi controls are you using which support pinning?

Comment: @JamesB For those of us that don't know, how do you set a Delphi form to have the pin button available in its non-client area?

Comment: @David, added notes to the question. "TForm with the border style set to bsSizeToolWin, Drag Kind set to dkDock and Drag Mode is dmAutomatic."

Comment: @JamesB when I do that, I don't get the pin button. Does it have to be docked?

Comment: @David, yes....I've just checked if I undock a form the pin button disappears.

Comment: I don't see a pin button at all. Are you using standard Delphi forms, or some third party add on?

Comment: Standard Delphi forms... There's an article here... http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33446 . The pin must be part of the TDockTabSet components.

Comment: @JamesB I'll download that source and see if I can work it out. You want an event to fire when the user clicks the pin. Also please remember to put @David in your comments if you want me to be notified!

Comment: @David, it's more about how to tell the difference between the user clicking the pin (which fires onhide) and the user clicking 'x' when the form is unpinned (which also fires onhide). I want the program to behave in 2 different ways depending on what caused the event to fire. Specifically if the user clicks 'x', I want to actually close the form.

Comment: @David, Downloaded the Demo, placed a breakpoint in TfrmDock.FormClose, Run the Demo, Clicked the clWhite tab (which is unpinned) to make the clWhite form appear, Clicked 'x' on clWhite. FormClose did not fire. TfrmMain.DockTabSet1TabRemoved did fire showing DockCaptionMouseUp in the call stack. Hope this helps!

Comment: @JamesB OK, I can get the same. I've been mixing up unpinned with undocked! Let's see if I can come up with a solution now!

Comment: @JamesB I'm out of ideas. I think in your shows I'd just stick with the behaviour that the VCL gives you. I just can't get my head round that code. I've deleted my answer. Sorry I was grumpy before.

Comment: @David, again thanks for your efforts.... I'll let you know what I come up with.  The VCL's handling of the *Close* on the unpinned, docked form just doesn't make sense to me... I **WISH** it called close!

Comment: Please note that if all you want to do is keep the menu synchronized with the form visibility, then you're going about this all wrong. Instead, attach a TAction to each menu item. In each action's OnUpdate event, check the visibility of the associated form and set the action's Checked property accordingly. Your program will automatically update the menu items whenever they're displayed to the user. But if you want to turn tab-hiding into closing, that's quite another matter having nothing to do with menus at all.

Comment: @Rob, Both... I want the hidden tab to be closed and I want the menu to know about it so it updates accordingly.  I don't suppose you know why hitting the 'x' on an unpinned tab doesn't close it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems that pinning and unpinning a docked form changes it's parent between a TTabDockPanel and the TPanel I'm docking it to.

Adding an OnHide method to the Demo Dock Form...

```
procedure TfrmDock.FormHide(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(Self.Parent) then
      ShowMessage(Self.Parent.ClassName)
  else 
      ShowMessage('No Parent');
end;
```

I can now distinguish between "Floating", "Docked,Pinned" and "Docked, Unpinned" when the form gets hidden.

**EDIT**
I've found a better way of doing this

```
procedure TfrmDock.FormHide(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if Assigned(Parent) then
    begin
        if Not (csDocking in ControlState) then //This was the original test above
        begin
            if Parent is TTabDockPanel then // This is now a safety check
            begin
                if TTabDockPanel(Parent).AnimateSpeed = 1 then //Additional Test
                    //form is closing
                else
                    //form is hiding (Unpinned focused changed)
            end;
        end
        else 
            //form is being unpinned.
    end;
end;
```

In `DockCaptionMouseUp` the Animation Speed is set to 1 so that the panel appears to close (Hides really fast).  The same happens for "Unpinning" but control state changes.